# .Net wrapper for Google Maps API V3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, google-maps

I found one .net wrapper for google maps api v3 [here.](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps/)

But in that link it has not mentioned weather it supports API V3 or not.
Also can some one point me towards using this dll in asp.net mvc 2 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how useful this answer is but here I go.

I wouldnt choose any wrapper out there without doing some research about the same. From the url that you shared looks like there is only 1 contributor to the project, also the dwnld count on the latest api is 117 which I dont think is a great number to warrant its use, there have only been 3 issues reported so far and from the looks of it they are inquiries or feature requests (not sure if it means that there are no bugs in the project or it hasn't been used).

Anyways having said that there are commercial wrappers out there which support google maps. I can think of [ThinkGeo](http://thinkgeo.com) for one. see if that is within your budget.

Now to your dll question. Just adding a reference in your web project should do the trick and then probably creating a seprate controller that serves your map. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: thanks for your response. i just wanted to explore the functionality of the the dll before using it on my project.

Comment: google-maps has moved to GitHub in the meantime `https://github.com/maximn/google-maps` and it looks up to date

Answer (score 0):

.NET wrapper libraries for the Google Maps API :

1. [GoogleApi](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi)
2. [google-maps](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531795